# How many stock investment strategies are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A venture capitalist wishes to invest $10K$ in four different stocks. Each investment
must be made in units of $1K$ and he wants to invest all of the money. How many
different possible investment strategies does he have if
(a) he wants to include all of the four stocks in his portfolio (i.e. to make a minimum investment of $1K$ in each stock)?
(b) he can invest in any number of the stocks (i.e. can allocate $0$ to one or more stocks)?

I have done part (a) and got $$\binom{10+4-1}{10} = 286$$ but I'm not sure how to go about (b). Can someone please help?

Comment: You should revisit $stars\;and\;bars$ to first check if you have used the correct formula for part (a)

Comment: This is not a probability question.  When you are counting the number of possibilities, it is a combinatorics question.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) argument to answer both questions.

For (a), the problem is equivalent to selecting where to place three (= 4-1) dividing bars in between a line of ten stars so as to create four nonempty groups like this one:

$$\star\star|\star\star\star\star|\star\star\star|\star$$

Given that there are nine (= 10-1) spaces between the stars, and we must choose three (= 4-1) spaces to put bars in, there are ${10-1\choose 4-1}$ ways of allocating 10 units among four groups so that each gets at least one.

For (b), the problem is equivalent to selecting where to place three (= 4-1) dividing bars in between a line of ten stars, where now we're allowed to have empty groups (which means multiple bars in a row for example):

$$\star\star\star\star|\star\star ||\star\star\star\star$$

Given that there will be 10+(4-1) characters in the list of stars and bars, and given that we must choose any three (=4-1) of them to be bars, there are $10+4-1 \choose 4-1$ ways to allocate 10 units among four groups, allowing for some groups to get nothing.